# Using NOIP with RPI node.js server

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, noip

Im no expert in networks so sorry if something seems stupid.

I'm having a problem connecting to RPI node.js server located in my home externally. I used NO-IP and configured it on router with specific host-name. I have port forwarded to 8888 port.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');
http.listen(8888, "0.0.0.0");

/*app.use(function (req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://hostname:port');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);    
    next();
});*/
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
app.get("/home",function(req,res,next){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});
console.log("server ubi jeza");
```

If I try to connect to http://hostanme.org it connect to my router. If I try connect to http://hostanme.org:8888 it times-off.

Port forward check works fine and says that port 8888 is working when I run the server. When server is not running it say that connection is closed.

I also tried with `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` and `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` but it doesn't work ither.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes I am, will post answer later xD

Answer (score 0):

I can access page from outside world. When I'm on local network I can not access it with external IP.

Comment: might be a dumb question, but I had an issue like this with my ISP.  They wouldnt allow me to go to my webserver on the network because of some loopback issue.  Not sure how to fix it other than accessing it off of the network